# Why is my NG-Controller not working in my code?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title>Using AngularJS Directives and Data Binding</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" /> 
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name ">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city | uppercase }}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<script src="scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
     var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[]); 
     angular.module('myapp').SimpleController('Ctrl', function($scope) { 
        $scope.customers = [
                            { name: 'Kobe Bryant', city: 'Philadelphia' }, 
                            { name: 'Magic Johnson', city: 'Lansing' },
                            { name: 'James Worthy', city: 'Gastonia' }
                        ];
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is just for learning purposes but I've been stuck trying to figure out why my NG-Controller isn't working for me. I think its a syntax error in how I write the .js part of the code.

Comment: There is no function named SimpleController in an angular module. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller. Open your browser console: it contains errors, that you MUST read before asking a question.

Comment: Not working has many meanings? Are you seeing any errors in the console? Create a fiddle and post it here, this will help others to help you quickly.

Comment: Change this line `angular.module('myapp').SimpleController('Ctrl', function($scope) { ` to `angular.module('myapp').controller('SimpleController', function($scope) { `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleController` should be your `controller` name, not the `function name` of angular module.

**Problem 1:**
Change

**`angular.module('myapp').SimpleController('Ctrl', function($scope)`**

to

**`angular.module('myapp').controller('SimpleController', function($scope)`**

**Problem 2:** You have a syntax error. **I fixed it in below snippet and plunker**

```js
     var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[]); 
     angular.module('myapp').controller('SimpleController', function($scope) { 
        $scope.customers = [
                            { name: 'Kobe Bryant', city: 'Philadelphia' }, 
                            { name: 'Magic Johnson', city: 'Lansing' },
                            { name: 'James Worthy', city: 'Gastonia' }
                        ];
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title>Using AngularJS Directives and Data Binding</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" /> 
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name ">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city | uppercase }}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kW2GViKBPytJKdCwN7fD?p=preview)

Comment: Changed the syntax and worked perfectly. Greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to help you. You can accept my answer if you find it useful.